# html5 video countdown time left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I ended up solving this issue by

```
   $oVideo.bind('timeupdate', function() {
   var currVideo = document.getElementById("vPlayer");
    //console.log(video.attr('id'));
   var iNow = currVideo.currentTime;
     //console.log(iNow);
   var countdown = eval(currVideo.duration - iNow);
     // countdown = countdown /3600;
   $('.decr-time').html('-' + rectime(countdown));


     if (!bTimeSlide) {
    $oTimeSlider.slider('value', iNow);

     }
  });
```

Hey I would like to thank anyone in advance.

I need to create a countdown timer for an HTML5 video. Here is what I have been able to piece together. I really appreciate anyone who can help me figure this out. My console isn't showing errors for the countdown; but my countdown does not seem to be working.

```
 //count down
  $oVideo.bind('duration', function() {
          var countdown = $oVideo.duration - $oVideo.currentTime;
            $down.text(rectime(countdown));
          if (! bTimeSlide)
              $oTimeSlider.slider('value', countdown);
        });
```

here is a snippit of the javaScript

```
        var $oMain = $(this);
        var $oVideo = $('video', $oMain);
        var $oTimeSlider = $('.time_slider', $oMain);
        var $oTimer = $('.timer', $oMain);
        var $down = ('.decr-time', $oMain);
        var bTimeSlide = false;

 //count up
        $oVideo.bind('timeupdate', function() {
          var iNow = $oVideo[0].currentTime;
            $oTimer.text(rectime(iNow));
            if (! bTimeSlide)
                $oTimeSlider.slider('value', iNow);
        });



 ///count down
  $oVideo.bind('duration', function() {
          var countdown = $oVideo.duration - $oVideo.currentTime;
            $down.text(rectime(countdown));
          if (! bTimeSlide)
              $oTimeSlider.slider('value', countdown);
        });
```

HTML

```
<section class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="video_player">
            <video controls>
               <source src="../assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <source src="../assets/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <source src="../assets/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
            </video>
                <div class="custom_controls">
                      <a href="index.html" title="Back" class="back-button"></a>
                      <a class="play" title="Play"></a>
                      <a class="pause" title="Pause"></a>
                      <div class="timer">00:00</div>
                      <div class="time_slider"></div>
                       <div class="decr-time">-00:00</div>
                      </div>
            </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the 'timeupdate' event fires, so you should be able do the countdown calcs/display in the same handler?

Based on the code in the question, ...

```
$oVideo.bind('timeupdate', function() {
    var video = $(this).get(0);
    var iNow = video.currentTime;
    var countdown = video.duration - iNow;

    $oTimer.text(rectime(iNow));
    $down.text(rectime(countdown));

    if (!bTimeSlide) {
        $oTimeSlider.slider('value', iNow);
    }
});
```

*edited*

Comment: Hello Beetroot thanks for your help, but that gave me back the value NaN:NaN

Comment: Just needs debugging; probably a question of getting the line `var countdown = $video.duration - iNow;` right. I based it on the code in the question. Try inspecting `$video.duration` to make sure it returns the value you expect.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, see edited code above.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot. this is what how i eneded up fixing it.